# Notification permission not changing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, notifications

I am testing notifications on chrome and firefox ofter 5 sec idle. In Firefox I get showed notification. In chrome after requestPermission() variable result inside this function changed. But when I try to show notification after timeout Notification.permission === 'default' and permissions not showing. OS - ubuntu. What is wrong in chrome? Why permission is default, not granted?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQHLazSsLs-TXZFZXB6TWVsa3M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I used index.html without any project and chrome didn't save url in settings as url for applying notifications. I started django project with index.html and save url localhost:8000 to chrome settings. Working!